# Magento external login will not create session cookie

Tags: session, magento, authentication, session-cookies, frontend

I am trying to replace a rather clumpsy ajax-login of Magento from an external site. The site uses Magento as a shop. Both the site and the magento-shop has their own logins, therefor when a user logs in it is important that both are synchronized. This was done with an ajax-call each page reload, keeping the user logged into Magento. I want to remove this so I created a check on each page reload which will do everything server-side.

My problem is, the following code does not work properly:

```
//Get Magento session-object
Mage::getSingleton("core/session", array("name"=>"frontend"));
$session = Mage::getSingleton("customer/session", array("name"=>"frontend"));

//Check if logged in
if(!$session->isLoggedIn()){                            
    //Not logged in, therefor log in 
    $mpassword = $this->getMagentoPassword();
    $musername = $this->getAddress();   
    try
    {
        $session->login($musername, $mpassword);    
    }catch(Exception $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }                            
}
```

Looking at cookies, there aren't any created, the ajax-login actually made a "frontend"-cookie. I know the code above actually logs in a user, but there aren't any session cookies created. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Magento only initializes the session with your code if the `$_SESSION` variable isn't set, i.e. `session_start()` wasn't called before the core session is instantiated.
Reference `Mage_Core_Model_Session_Abstract_Varien::start()` for details.

As a solution, the easiest way would be to start the Magento session during a request **before** the other session of your site is started.
Otherwise you will have to duplicate the code that sets the session name to `frontend` and initializes the Magento session cookie.

Comment: Thanks alot for this, it certainly did the trick and I was suspecting it as a problem aswell. Once more, thanks!