# Magento session creation destroys other session variables

Tags: php, magento, session-variables

I am using Mage::getSingleton("customer/session") to be able to login to Magento externally. Problem is, this seems to clear up other $_SESSION variables I have set.

How can I have the entire cake and be able to login to Magento plus setting normal SESSION-variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume this answer might apply to you also: [Magento external login will not create session cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9206397/magento-external-login-will-not-create-session-cookie/9206847#9206847)
In essence try first creating the Magento session before you create the other session.

If that doesn't help you might need to provide additional code so a good answer can be supplied.

Comment: Vinai, that is actually the code I am using. The problem is while using this the other session-variables get cleared by some reason. My magento-sessions are kept but the other ones are erased.

Comment: Nevermind, actually figured this out, was a hidden session_start that messed it up.